# MacBook Pro shuts down if no key is pressed

Tags: hardware-failure, macbook-pro

Today, when I tried to turn on my MacBook Pro it shut down while it was booting.

I found out that it always happens if no key has been pressed on the keyboard for 10-15 seconds. It also happens in normal boot, safe boot, single user mode, hardware test & recovery mode.

If I hold down a key (any key, eg. Caps Lock), everything else works perfectly and I can use my computer normally.

I have tried resetting both PRAM and SMC, however this had no positive effect. After resetting the SMC, nothing happened after pressing the power button, and after I somehow fixed this, the fan is running at full speed at all time and OS X says that it have "No batteries available", even when running on batteries!

Resetting the SMC doesn't fix this, as I tried resetting it at least 5 times now.

Have anyone experienced anything similar as the keyboard thing?